# Can not delete site with AppOnly Permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I am trying to delete the site with app only permissions.

Below is my Provider Hosted app permissions

```
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true" >
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Below is the code I am trying

```
using (var ctx = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(
                                <TenantAdminUrl> // Tenant Url
                                , <ClientID> // Client Id
                                , <ClientSecret>)) // Client Secret

{
    var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
    var removeSite = tenant.RemoveSite(<siteurl>);
    ctx.Load(removeSite);
    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
}
```

Above code is giving me following error

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access
>   this resource.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream
>   responseStream)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)

**Update: 7/11**
The site is read-only. Is there a way I can delete read-only site?

Tried below code to update site status and it doesn't throw any exception and does not remove read only flag.

```
using (var ctx = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(
   <TenantAdminUrl>
   , <ClientID>
   , <ClientSecret>)) // Client Secret
{
   var tenant = new Tenant(ctx);
   tenant.SetSiteLockState(<SiteUrl>, OfficeDevPnP.Core.SiteLockState.Unlock,true);
}
```

Comment: Does the current user who is performing the step is having "FullControl" access? As to perform an action via add-in, authorization (i.e. by user+add-in policy) is succeeded only when both the current user and the add-in have permission to perform that action.

Comment: can you do the app registration process on the tenant site collection and then check ? If you have registered the app on any other site collection, AFAIK it didnt work. I could be wrong though !

Comment: @DivyaSharma This is running with Azure Job and not running with specific user

Comment: @GautamSheth other api is working for e.g. tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters. Problem is with "tenant.RemoveSite"

Comment: @DivyaSharma I forgot to mention that site is read only

Comment: @GautamSheth I forgot to mention that site is read only

Comment: Are you trying to open the site (i.e. marked as read-only) with the Site Collection Administrator?

Comment: In order to delete the site I first had to open the site. Without that it doesn't work